# How to find the variance and expectation of MLE estimator?

Tags: regression, self-study, maximum-likelihood, unbiased-estimator, estimators

I have a linear regression model with
$Y=X\beta+\epsilon$. $\epsilon$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$

MLE estimate of $\beta$ is $\beta_{MLE}={(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY}$ and MLE estimate of $\sigma^2_{MLE}=1/n(Y-XB)^T(Y-XB)$. I want to know what is the expectation and variance of $\sigma^2_{MLE}$.

Comment: 1. is this work for some subject? 2. Where you have MEL do you mean MLE?

Comment: 1- It's related to the hierarchal linear model and 2- Yes. I corrected it.

Comment: I am not asking for the topic, I am asking whether this arises from coursework or something similar. It reads like a homework- or textbook- style of question.

Comment: It's part of a question I need to solve. I have a little hard time to find the answer.

Comment: Please carefully read our [help/on-topic] in relation to homework-style questions.

Comment: It's not clear why you deleted. The thing I asked you to read makes it clear such questions are welcome. It just asks you to do a few simple things. "Homework questions are welcome. Please mark them with the self-study tag. They get somewhat special treatment, because ultimately you benefit most by finding the solution yourself. The community will try to provide guidance, hints, and useful links." ... the `self-study` tag wiki explains some more.